# How to write if in Odoo

Tags: odoo, point-of-sale, odoo-15

I'm trying to edit the xml of Odoo POS receipt, I'm going to add the following
If TAX no. feild of the customer is filled in, then write it (on the receipt)

I wrote this

```
<t t-if='receipt.client'>
<div>------------****--------------</div>
<div>Customer</div>
<div><t t-esc="env.pos.get_client().name"/></div>
<div>TAX ID:<t t-esc="receipt.client.vat"/></div>
<div><t t-esc="receipt.client.street"/> <t t-esc="receipt.client.street2"/> - <t t-esc="receipt.client.city"/><t t-esc="receipt.client.state_id"/></div>
</t>
```

So.. when I didn't fill in TAX feild, I expected `t-if` in the begining will do the function . But the result was (VAT ID: False). The same with street and street2
I want to write if for all the above data.
Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Did you inherit the template correctly? It should be enclosed in something like the following:

```
<template id="insert_your_template_id" inherit_id="module.template_you_are_inheriting">
```